# To get no warning in running PHP in Ubuntu's terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu

I run

```
php test_code.php
```

I get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
-- I get the right output after these strange Warnings --
```

The files do not exist in the warnings.

**How can you get no warnings in running PHP in Ubuntu's terminal?**

Comment: Do you mean, "how do you hide warnings" or "how do you fix this error"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search at [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) shows these are in the php5-gd and php5-mcrypt.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 2):

Either:

A) Install missing libraries
OR
B) Remove gd and mcrypt modules from your php.ini
OR
C) Remove error reporting, which is really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

A reply this to this bug post on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/281979 solved the problem for me.

In short remove the .ini files. In my case the following commands worked:

```
/etc/php5/conf.d# rm mcrypt.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d# rm suhosin.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the error_reporting ini value to 0, which means no error notices:

```
php -d error_reporting=0 test_code.php
```

Although, you should probably try and fix those errors.

Answer (score 1):

PHP-GD and PHP-MCrypt are installed correctly?

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

are there?

If not:

```
# apt-get install php5-gd php5-mcrypt
```